# Javascript: silently fail on undefined assignment

Tags: javascript

Suppose I am trying to assign a variable in a way that causes an exception

I am going to access a non-existent key of a dictionary:

```
myObject.property = dictionary['NO_KEY'][0];
```

Now, because 'NO_KEY' does not exist on dictionary, my program will catch an exception when trying to subscript 0 of undefined - and crash. Is it possible to execute this line above as a no-op so that my script can continue running? I know there is try-catch syntex, but is there a more elegant syntax with ESMA6?

Comment: `(dictionary['NO_KEY'] || {})[0]` though it's ugly :-)

Comment: What is expected resulting value of `myObject.property` if `dictionary["NO_KEY"]` is not defined?

Comment: another ugly way - `var silentsWillFall = (obj, ...path) => path.reduce((ret, key) => (ret = ret && ret[key]), obj);` - ugly because it's use would be `myObject.property = silentsWillFall (dictionary, 'NO_KEY', 0);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `if` condition and statement, `Object.hasOwnProperty()` or as suggested by @Ryan `in` operator

```
if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty("NO_KEY")) {
  myObject.property = dictionary["NO_KEY"][0];
}
```

```
if ("NO_KEY" in dictionary) {
  myObject.property = dictionary["NO_KEY"][0];
}
```

Comment: For easier reading and resilience against `hasOwnProperty` being a key in the dictionary, `if ("NO_KEY" in dictionary)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid - having to check if the property exists. I just want something that silently fails.

Comment: What do you mean by "silently fails"? What is expected resulting value of `myObject.property`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 
                      'accessWithSilentFail', { 
                       configurable: false,
                       enumerable: false, 
                       writable: false, 
                       value: function(key) {
                         return this[key] ? this[key] : {};
                       }});

myObject.property = dictionary
                     .accessWithSilentFail('NO_KEY')
                     .accessWithSilentFail(0);
```

That way you get an empty object if at any point the chain fails. You need to get an object so the chain doesn't fail halfway. You can call the function something shorter if you're going to use it a lot.

Although this works, it has many, many limitations, and it changes the Object prototype, which is usually frowned upon. You really should consider just checking for undefined, which is the idiomatic way to do it.

If you ever need to check if the access chain failed, you can use:

```
function chainFailed(result) {
    return Object.keys(result).length === 0;
}
```

So you could do

```
myObject.property = dictionary
                      .accessWithSilentFail('NO_KEY')
                      .accessWithSilentFail(0);

if (!chainFailed(myObject.property)) {
  //keep on
} else {
  //handle failure
}
```

This works as long as your expected return isn't an empty object, on which case chainFailed will always return true. But I'm assuming you really want to fail silently, because if you wanted to handle errors you could just use an exception.

Comment: Changing the `Object.prototype` (and every other built-in prototype) is an awful idea.

Comment: It can be useful when used carefully and in extreme moderation, although I admit that changing it recklessly is a bad idea. But it's the most elegant way to express what OP has asked for. I believe any other way would be quite clunky.

Comment: "But it's the most elegant way" --- it's not: if you see it, you have no clue where it's defined. And also it's iterable.

Comment: I think where this would be defined would be something that would need to be documented regardless, as I'm assuming it would be used all over the place.

Comment: If by iterable you mean enumerable, I fixed that.

Comment: @PedroCastilho thanks for you answer. I would never use this but this is just so cool :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator

```
myObject.property = dictionary['NO_KEY'] ? dictionary['NO_KEY'][0] : null;
```

Comment: It's short, but I just don't like that 'dictionary['NO_KEY']' appears twice. Don't repeat yourself violation. But it's nice!

Answer (score 0):

While I believe this is a bad idea that will come back to bite you later, here is a solution for modern browsers using [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Yes, you are still checking for the property existence, but it is hidden from your code accessing the dictionary keys.

```js
var dictionary = {a: 42};

dictionary = new Proxy(dictionary, {
    get: (target, property) => {
        if (target.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            return target[property];
        }
        return {};
    }
});

// Existing properties are passed through unchanged
console.log(dictionary.a);
// Missing properties result in an empty object
console.log(dictionary.b);
// Original test
var lost = dictionary['NO_KEY'][0];
console.log(lost);
```